# Is there a way to create a new column if 2 of 3 values in specified columns are 1?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set with 3 replicates per sample group, and I want to determine if there are >= 2 valid values per group.

For example:

| UniqueID | a_1 | a_2 | a_3 | b_1 | b_2 | b_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Second | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Third | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Ideally, I want to generate a new dataframe that summarizes this, where 1 means "yes, there >= 2 valid values, and 0 means "there is less than 2 valid values". For example:

| UniqueID | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 0 |
| Second | 0 | 1 |
| Third | 1 | 0 |

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df1 %>% transmute(UniqueID, a = +(rowSums(across(starts_with("a_"))) >1), b= +(rowSums(across(starts_with("b_"))) >1))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution.

```r
x <- 'UniqueID  a_1     a_2     a_3     b_1     b_2     b_3
First   1   1   0   1   0   0
Second  1   0   0   1   1   1
Third   1   1   1   0   0   0'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

a <- grep("^a", names(df1))
b <- grep("^b", names(df1))

df2 <- cbind(
  UniqueID = df1['UniqueID'],
  a = as.integer(rowSums(df1[a]) >= 2),
  b = as.integer(rowSums(df1[b]) >= 2)
)
df2
#>   UniqueID a b
#> 1    First 1 0
#> 2   Second 0 1
#> 3    Third 1 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>